# How to get this function to work with Rbutton?

Tags: autohotkey

This is something I have been working on for the past few days, I am at the last hurdle now.

I am wondering if someone can help me understand where I am going wrong here, specifically with triggering the function.

I want the function and its GUIs window show only while `Rbutton` is down but as soon as `Rbutton` is released the function/GUI window should exit and return a value:

```
RButton & WheelDown::
RButton & WheelUp::
Var := Gui_Win()
Return

Gui_Win(){
    static
    If !WinExist("Gui_Win ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI ahk_exe AutoHotkey.exe"){         ;If GUI already exists, then simply update control value
        Gui Main:New,+AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, Gui_Win
        Gui Main:Font,s14,Consolas
        Gui Main:Add,Edit           , vvCONopacity Center x+4 y04 w80 Disabled, 55
        
        MouseGetPos mX,mY
        CoordMode, Mouse, Screen 
        Gui Main:Show,% "x" mX " y" mY " w120 h40"             

        ControlGetPos, con1X, con1Y, con1W, con1H, Edit1, % "ahk_ID " MainHwnd
        WinGetPos wX,wY,wW,wH,% "ahk_ID " MainHwnd         
    }
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen 
    MouseGetPos mX,mY,mW,mC                                  
    Gui Main:Submit,NoHide        
    If (A_ThisHotkey~="Up")                 
        vCONopacity++                                          
    Else                                                
        vCONopacity--

    GuiControl Main:,Edit1,% vCONopacity:=Format("{:0.1f}",vCONopacity)  

;------ With the following Lines commented out, the function works------
    KeyWait, Rbutton
    Gui Main:Hide                                        
    Gui Main:Submit, NoHide  

    OutPut := vCONopacity
    Return OutPut
}
```

It seems having the line `KeyWait, Rbutton` in the function essentially break it.  As soon as I comment out everything after the `------` line, the GUI works, I can increment with the wheel etc, but then releasing `Rbutton` does nothing.

I have created several tests to get to the crux of the issue and I have not discovered the issue:

```
RButton & WheelDown::
RButton & WheelUp::
GUI_Test()
Return

GUI_Test(){
    while GetKeyState("RButton", "p"){   ;Do this while Rbutton is down
    If (A_ThisHotkey ~= "Up")
        ToolTip, Wheelup
    Else
        ToolTip, WheelDown
    }
    MsgBox, Rbutton Is Up!               ;Do this when Rbutton is released
}
```

The above test, tells me that the `Msgbox` is correctly fired (only when `Rbutton` is released), but the `WheelUp` and `WhellDown` only fire once, instead of continuously firing while `Rbutton` is down. The following test also seems to suffer from the same issue as above:

```
RButton & WheelDown::
GUI_Test()
RButton & WheelUp::
GUI_Test()
Return

GUI_Test(){
    If (A_ThisHotkey ~= "Up")
        ToolTip, Wheelup
    Else
        ToolTip, WheelDown
    
    KeyWait, RButton
    MsgBox, up
}
```

The function that I shared is a bare bones version of what I have in mind, the actual function takes in values and generates one or more controls as requested.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use SetTimer for waiting of the Rbutton to be released.

Comment: @user3419297, I was able to get it working with an `If` / `Else If` condition inside the function. Thanks!